# Using tabs in gvim along with specific number of lines and columns

Tags: vim

I have a problem with a setting in my gvimrc.  I like to always have all windows the same size so I specify the following:

set lines=90
set columns=90

This works fine except when I open gvim with the -p argument for multiple tabs.  The statusline and ruler are hidden until I manually resize the window.  This only happens when the lines/columns are specified AND I use the -p argument.  Is there a way to prevent this on startup other than manually dragging the window around to redraw the ruler/statusline?

I'm using gvim 7.3.154 in ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Windows (using different values of lines and columns than 90, since that won't fit on my screen, but nevertheless). laststatus=2 I suppose? If you don't find a solution here, put a bug report on vim's page/mailing list with your OS data.

Comment: This problem doesn't happen to me using macvim with the same settings.  It seems to only happen in Linux.  Where exactly is the best place to post a bug for gvim?

Comment: It's usually best to report it on vim-dev@vim.org (see http://www.vim.org/community.php), and check out the opinions on irc.freenode.net #vim. Several vim devs there. Once you got it and know how to reproduce it, go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is actually spelled out when reading the gvim documentation on 'lines', see :help lines.

from :help lines

"If you get less lines than expected, check the 'guiheadroom' option.
When you set this option and Vim is unable to change the physical
number of lines of the display, the display may be messed up."

I was able to set guiheadroom=100 on my system and avoid this problem completely.  The 100 was just a guess on my part.  The default value for this is 50, so if you run into this problem you should set it to something > 50.  I was able to go as small as 80, but your mileage will most likely vary depending on your OS, window manager, etc.